# How to copy all policies from one branch to another on Azure Devops with Az Cli

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, command-line-interface, cicd

I need to automate the creation of a new branch from another and copy all the policies from the source branch. This will happen inside a YAML pipeline in ADO and Im implementing it via az cli.

At the moment Im stuck at this point, I was able to retrieve the policy list from a specified repo and branch:

```bash
REPOID=$(az repos list --query "[?name == '<nameOfRepo>'].id" --output tsv)  
POLICIES=$(az repos policy list --branch develop --repository-id $REPOID)
```

But from this point I can't find from the [documentation command list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/policy?view=azure-cli-latest#commands) a command that helps me do that, because only specific policies creation are supported (create build policy, create reviewer policy...).

I found [this](https://www.ppanesar.com/azure/copy-branch-policies/) article, but it explains only the creation of build policies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following PowerShell script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]

param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $AzureDevOpsPAT,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $OrganizationName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $teamProjectName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $repositoryName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $fromBranch,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $toBranch
)


$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';

$User="";

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $User,$AzureDevOpsPAT)));
$header = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)};

# Get repository
$Url = 'https://dev.azure.com/'+ $OrganizationName + '/' + $teamProjectName + '/_apis/git/repositories/' + $repositoryName +'?api-version=5.1'
$repository = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $header

$Url = 'https://dev.azure.com/'+ $OrganizationName + '/' + $teamProjectName + 
            '/_apis/git/policy/configurations?repositoryId=' + $repository.id + '&refName=refs/heads/' + $fromBranch + '&api-version=5.1-preview.1'

# get policies
$policies = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $header

$Url = 'https://dev.azure.com/'+ $OrganizationName + '/' + $teamProjectName + '/_apis/policy/configurations?api-version=5.1';


foreach($policy in $policies.value)
{
    if ($policy.type.id -eq '0517f88d-4ec5-4343-9d26-9930ebd53069') 
    {
        continue; # skipping GitRepositorySettingsPolicyName
    }

    # remove properties from policy so it can be applied to target branch
    $props = $policy.PSObject.Properties
    $props.remove('createdBy');
    $props.remove('createdDate');
    $props.remove('revision');
    $props.remove('id');
    $props.remove('url');

    $policy._links.PSObject.Properties.Remove('self')

    # set target branch

    if (($null -ne $policy.settings.scope[0].refname))
    {
        $policy.settings.scope[0].refName = 'refs/heads/' + $toBranch;
    }
    if (($null -ne $policy.settings.searchBranches))
    {
        $policy.settings.searchBranches[0] = 'refs/heads/' + $toBranch;
    }

    # create policy in target branch
    
    $body = $policy | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

    $policyCreateResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType application/json -Headers $header
    $policyCreateResponse
}
```

Usage: `.\PolicyCopy.ps1 -AzureDevOpsPAT 'yourPAT' -OrganizationName 'test' -teamProjectName 'test' -repositoryName 'test' -fromBranch 'master' -toBranch 'feature'`

Source: [here](https://chamindac.blogspot.com/2020/04/copy-azure-git-repo-branch-policies.html).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by creating a policy from the portal matching a certain prefix in branches given that other solutions were too hard to maintain.

(Go to branch lists and you can write a policy for branches that start with a certain prefix like /release)

I also scrapped the idea of writing a Policy Configuration file given the lack of documentation for them.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/257

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/185